# Streamlit dynamic text based on slider below

Tags: streamlit

Streamlit makes dynamic text, based on a slider value, super easy:

```py
value = st.slider('Slide me', 0, 100, 50)
if value > 80:
    st.warning('Value is too big!')
```

How do I issue this warning **above** the slider? This doesn't work:

```py
if value > 80:
    st.warning('Value is too big!')
value = st.slider('Slide me', 0, 100, 50)
```

The warning will never get displayed when sliding over 80 (actually I'd get an error that `value` is undefined so I have to set `value = 0` at the top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a [container](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.container) (or using [st.empty](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.empty)) above the slider and then fill it in the conditional that runs after the slider:

```
container = st.container()
value = st.slider('Slide me', 0, 100, 50)
if value > 80:
    container.warning('Value is too big!')
```

It could be possible that st.warning does not go "into" the container, then you'd have to define your own warning banner to put in there. Sorry, cannot test it currently.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you @Johannes. Note that `container.st.warning()` should be `container.warning()`.